# How to run `dnu build` on DNX projects that lack a solution file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, dnx

I'm curious if it's possible to run `dnu build` on C# projects that only have `project.json` and `global.json` files, and lack all of the MSBuild setup like `.sln` and `.xproj`. Here is what my directory structure looks like:

```
LibFoo/
-global.json
-src/
--LibFoo/
---project.json
---QuuxBar.cs
-test/
--LibFoo.Tests
---project.json
---QuuxBarTests.cs
```

When I `cd` to the repo root and run `dnu build global.json`, here is the output I get:

```
$ dnu build global.json
Microsoft .NET Development Utility Mono-x64-1.0.0-rc1-16231

Unable to locate project.json.
Total build time elapsed: 00:00:00.0017763
Total projects built: 1
```

What should I do? Should I run some kind of hackish thing where I find all of the `project.json` files within the directory and run `dnu build` on them? Is there any way to do this without having explicit knowledge of all the subprojects within the repo?

For example, if this was my build script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

dnu build src/LibFoo/project.json
dnu build test/LibFoo.Tests/project.json
```

and then I added 10 more projects under the `src/` directory, what would be a way to make this work without adding 10 more lines to the build script?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @aguafrommars said, you can use KoreBuild but we're not offering any support for that nor we guarantee that we're not going to make a breaking change. It's just an infrastructure project that happens to be public.

But, what KoreBuild does is it looks for the folders that contain a project.json under a specified folder and invokes `dnu` (or `dotnet`) `build` on them. Nothing fancy, just a for loop. It could be easily replicated in batch, PowerShell or Bash. https://github.com/aspnet/KoreBuild/blob/dev/build/shade/_k-standard-goals.shade#L144-L145

Answer (score 1):

The `aspnet` team use [`KoreBuild`](https://github.com/aspnet/KoreBuild) which are [`Sake`](https://github.com/sakeproject/sake) scripts to build and test the `AspNet Core` stack.
You can use the same tools.